# Переход на определённую позицию на странице

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Здравствуйте!

Вот захотелось вставить себе на сайта такую вещицу как в [ru.wikipedia.org](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jquery) Сначала идет меню с содержанием, при выборе определенного пункта, переход осуществляется на этой же странице, в то место где находится та или иная информация.

И пользуясь случаем хотел бы узнать как осуществить

- плавный переход
- при добавлении новых пунктов в меню в html чтобы не приходилось лезть в js код

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Зачем изобретать велосипед? Юзайте <id="NameMenu"> и будет Вам счастье.

Answer (score 3):

Примерно так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a[href*=#]').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var target_top= $('a[name="'+this.href.split("#")[1]+'"]').offset().top;
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 'slow');
 });
});
</script>
<a href="#bottom">Вниз</a>
<div style="height: 2000px;"></div>
<a name="bottom">Низ</a>
```

Comment: вот оно - высший класс!)))

Comment: омг, зачем тут еще javascript

Comment: @shurik, в тегах стоит jquery. А каким еще образом сделать что-то плавно? css?))

Answer (score 1):

читайте про якоря. допустим, есть страница с большим количеством разделов. один из разделов имеет `id="razdel_one"`. тогда ссылка `<a href="name_page.html#razdel_one` приведет именно к этому разделу, прокрутит страницу до этого якоря. мат.часть надо зубрить и понимать.

ну а плавный переход это Вас надо читать про `scrollTop` или `scrollTo`. там можно указать скорость прокрутки.

Comment: Этот способ как бы не устраивает, необходимо сделать не используя классы,если у нас будет не 1-2 пункта а 100 то нам придется прописывать для каждого свой класс... Как можно сделать с помощью jQuery

Comment: а причём здесь классы? ладно, понятно. в jQuery есть метод `.eq()` и фильтр `:eq()`. например `div:eq(40)` вернёт 41 `div` из Ваших ста.

Comment: попробуйте плагин [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/)

Comment: то что ты написал div:eq(40) это мы указываем на ссылку в меню, а для дива с информацией мы ничего не указываем или мы и там что то должны указать, типа интекса

Comment: он просто находится на странице. с помощью этого метода (или фильтра) находим положение элемента на странице (метод `.position()`) и скроллим до него, с помощью указанных выше методов прокрутки.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="blockMenu"> 
     <tr> 
       <td> 
         <div class="leftBg">  
           <div class="active">Основное меню</div> 
           <div>Салаты</div> 
           <div>Напитки</div>  <br/>
         </div> 
       </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

У меня нет ссылок, я делаю Дивами, как прописать условие для дивов,с ссылками вроде все ясно, вот с дивами не очень, как прописать условие поиска и типа якоря

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){<br/>
 $('.menuSection').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();<br/>
  var target_top= $('.buttonMainMenu[menuSectionName="'+$(this).text()+'"]').offset().top;<br/>
  
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_top-100}, 'slow');<br/>
 });
});
<br/>
 <div class="buttonMainMenu" menuSectionName = "Основное меню">Основное меню</div>

Comment: А вы правда не видите, что ваше постоянное <br/> так и отпечатывается, или это стиль у вас такой?) Здесь блоки отделяются двумя переносами.