# Переход на определенное место в сайте

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Вот появилась такая задача, связанная с переходом на определенный пункт на странице. Я как бы справился с этой задачей, вот только при повторном клике, скролл поднимается на 10-15 пикселев на вверх и останавливается, откуда он берет это не могу понять.

Заранее спасибо!!

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: 0
      }, 'slow');
      $('.menuSection').click(function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var target_top = $('.buttonMainMenu[menuSectionName="' + $(this).text() + '"]').offset().top;
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: target_top - 100
          }, 'slow');
      });
```

Меню ссылок, на который производится **click**

```
<div id="blockMenu">
        <div class="leftBg">
           <div class="menuSection">Ссылка1</div>
           <div class="separator"></div>
           <div class="menuSection">Ссылка2</div>
           <div class="separator"></div>
           <div class="menuSection">Ссылка3</div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Тот якорь, куда нужно перейти.

```
<div class="buttonMainMenu" menuSectionName = "Ссылка1">Ссылка1</div>
```

Comment: Либо у вас что-то происходит с высотой div[menuSectionName="Ссылка1"], либо страницу в студию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот в этом вопросе - [переход на определённую позицию на странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/63700/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=63701#63701) - уже обсуждалась подобная тема. И @Sh4dow предложил очень красивое решение.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно отсюда: [якоря](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya).

> Якорем называется закладка с уникальным именем на определенном месте веб-страницы, предназначенная для создания перехода к ней по ссылке. Якоря удобно применять в документах большого объема, чтобы можно было быстро переходить к нужному разделу.
>
> Для создания якоря следует вначале сделать закладку в соответствующем месте и дать ей имя при помощи атрибута name тега <a></a> (пример 9.1). В качестве значения href для перехода к этому якорю используется имя закладки с символом решетки (#) впереди.
>
> Пример 9.1. Создание якоря
>
> `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
> <html>
>  <head>
>   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
>   <title>Быстрый переход внутри документа</title>
>  </head>
>  <body>
>   <p><a name="top"></a></p>
>   <p>...</p>
>   <p><a href="#top">Наверх</a></p>
>  </body>
> </html>`
>
> Между тегами `<a name="top">` и `</a>` текст не обязателен, так как требуется лишь указать местоположение перехода по ссылке, находящейся внизу страницы. Имя ссылки на якорь начинается с символа #, после чего идет имя якоря, оно выбирается любое, соответствующее тематике. Главное, чтобы значения атрибутов name и href совпадали (символ решетки не в счет).

И второе, зачем для такого использовать jQuery? Что простой html уже вообще не катит?

Comment: А чтобы решить именно эту задачу.</br>Пытаюсь понять откуда он берет этот отступ. </br>
При повторном клике на него от точки останова отступает на пикселев 10-15. и больше ни каких изменений

Comment: при повторном клике на каком элементе?вот этот момент не совсем ясен

Comment: На ту же ссылку куда и был произведен click. и это значение осле остается постоянно